# Can I install both x86/x64 windbg on my x64 WIN7?

Tags: x86, 64-bit, windbg

I need to analysis some x86 dump file, So I want to install the x86 windbg on my computer.

or if I can use the x64 windbg to analysis the x86 dump file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, and it is a good idea to do so since you'll need the 32 bit version to debug 32 bit applications/dumps. All the files are located in the install directory, so you can have any number of installations side by side.

Also, keep in mind that if you use a 64 bit tool to create a dump, you'll get a 64 bit dump - even if the process is 32 bit. In that case you'll get a dump of the WoW64 process, which makes debugging the dump a bit more difficult. However, if you use a 32 bit tool to create the dump file, you'll get a regular 32 bit dump and then you can use the 32 bit debugger as you normally would.

Comment: Additional to what @Brian had mentioned FYI Debugging tools for windows does not require any installation, just xcopy.

Comment: @Naveen: I did it using installation. can you let me know how to use it using xcopy?

Comment: @Rockstart You would just have to copy to share and use it from the share. For example I have x86 and x64 debugging tools copied on to a shared drive ( Copy the whole directory) and anytime I have to debug I  just open the debugger from that location and I don't have to install it on any system.