# 64 or 32 bit version of WinDBG?

Tags: vmware, windbg, remote-debugging

I have a 64 bit host OS and a 32 bit guest OS running inside VMWare. I want to use WinDBG to debug 32 bit guest OS from my 64 bit host OS. Which version of WinDBG should I install? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/3797275/38206

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 64-bit WinDBG can debug 32 bit targets.

Essentially, you should install the package that's appropriate for the host - that package can attach to whatever target type.

Answer (score 0):

If your PC has a 64 bit-capable processor (CPU), you can install a 64-bit version of Windows 7, even if you are currently running a 32-bit version. However, to install a 64-bit version of Windows 7 on a computer already running a 32-bit version, you'll need to back up your files and choose the Custom option during installation. Then, you'll need to restore your files and reinstall your programs