# Get the dump using Taskbar, Process Explorer , AdPlus etc

Tags: windbg, process-explorer

Are those dump the full dump? What's the best dump which can be analyzed later using Windbg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task manager, process explorer and AdPlus are all able to create full user mode dumps, which will contain all the details needed for debugging using WinDbg.

Special attention is required when creating dumps for 32 bit processes running on 64 bit Windows. Please see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797275/can-i-install-both-x86-x64-windbg-on-my-x64-win7/3797405#3797405) for additional detail.